# EventEmitter и проверка заполнения объекта

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть события (events) на которые я подписываюсь (данные события делают запрос на сторонний сервис и получают информацию). После получения информации, я заполняю объект данными.

Загвоздка в том, что я хочу дождаться заполнения объекта всеми данными и в дальнейшем передать его дальше...

Пример кода:

```
function checkAccountInfo() {
    let accountInfo = {};

    event.on('anyEvent1', function(name) {
        accountInfo.name = name;
    });

    event.on('anyEvent2', function(address) {
        accountInfo.address = address;
    });
}
```

Промисы (Promise) здесь, как я понял бесполезны, так как коннект/запрос/ответ с небольшой задержкой... И промис в любом случае даёт положительный (resolve) результат (даже если ответ ещё не пришёл)

Каким способом лучше проверить заполнение объекта? Или же есть более простой способ в моём случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать промисы.

```js
// Эмуляция асинхронных операций
const event = {
  on: function(name, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(name);
    }, Math.round(Math.random() * 4000));
  }
}

function checkAccountInfo() {
  let accountInfo = {};
  let promiseName = new Promise(resolve => {
    event.on('anyEvent1', function(name) {
      accountInfo.name = name;
      resolve(name);
    });
  });

  let promiseAddress = new Promise(resolve => {
    event.on('anyEvent2', function(address) {
      accountInfo.address = address;
      resolve(address);
    });
  });
  Promise.all([promiseName, promiseAddress]).then((res) => {
    console.log(res, accountInfo);
  });
}
checkAccountInfo();
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Вы открыли мне глаза на промисы!